# SYBUNT (some year but not this year) showing 2011 as this year

Tags: civireport

When doing this option in civireport or LYBUNT (last year but not this year) Its showing this year as 2011.[image: SYBUNT YEAR 2011]

everything else is showing the correct years...
why is this not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample report instance has the filter saved at 2011. If you do a new create report from template it defaults to current year.

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1091

Comment: Thank you. Very strange that they do it this way. There should be a way to create new reports from that page.